# Named Pipe connection between Host and Guest with Virtualbox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, named-pipe

I have two apps which communicate over a named pipe (Unix domain socket) - all on one machine. I cannot figure out how to get the app in the VirtualBox VM (Linux) to open the named pipe on the host (Centos7).

I have mounted the shared folder so the Linux VM can see the shared folder containing the named pipe "file". But when it tries to connect to it, it gets ECONNREFUSED (no one listening).

The only thing I could see in the VirtualBox Manager was a section on setting Serial Ports to point to named pipes. But I want my app in the VM to connect to the actual named pipe, not COM1.

Is this possible?